# Java JNI run class from module

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to create an executable file that runs a Java project similar to how e.g. Launch4j and similar projects do. The difference is that Launch4j merely launches the `.jar`, so it will be its own process. I want to create the JVM using JNI so that I have full control over the projects thread, enabling further customization of the programs appearance in native contexts.

My java project gets compiled using `jlink` to create a custom, minimal runtime for the project. This will also, in case someone didn't know, add the java project itself as well to the runtime. You can try running `java.exe -m "project.module.name/project.module.name.Main"` and it will run the project directly from the runtime.

This is basically the C++ code I'm running right now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <jni.h>
#include "resources.h"

int main () {
/* Used in production mode to avoid a console window
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE  hInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                    int       nCmdShow) {
*/


    JavaVM *jvm;       /* Java VM */
    JNIEnv *env;       /* Pointer to native method interface */
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* VM initialization arguments */
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_10;

    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[0];

    vm_args.nOptions = 0;

    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT(".\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll")); /* Loads the custom jvm.dll created by jlink */
    typedef jint(JNICALL *pCreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **, void**, void *); /* Defines jint */
    pCreateJavaVM CreateJavaVM = (pCreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "JNI_CreateJavaVM"); /* Pointer to the JNI_CreateJavaVM function inside the custom jvm.dll */

    jint res = CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args); /* Create the java VM and save the success/fail result of starting it */

    if (res < 0) { /* Negative values are errors */
        std::cout << "Couldn't run VM. Error: " << res << std::endl;
        delete options;
        jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
        return res;
   } else {
        /* This is where the crashing happens */
        jclass clazz = env->FindClass("project.module.name.Main");
        if (clazz == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Couldn't find the class" << std::endl;
            env->ExceptionDescribe();
            jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
            return -1;
        } else {
            jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;])V"); /* Get the main function of the class */
            env->CallStaticVoidMethod(clazz, mid, ""); /* Run the main function */

            delete options;
            jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
        }
   }

    std::cout << "Ending..." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs as far as that I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find the class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: project.module.name.Main
```

My initial idea was that perhaps what I need to do is run the JVM with the classpath set to the location of a jar version of the Java project, but again that shouldn't be necessary since the runtime already has the project inside of it.

Is there a way of running the JVM with options that functions similar to `-m "project.module.name/project.module.name.Main"` that you can use with `java.exe`? Of course that exactly doesn't work (I tried) because those are options of `java.exe`, not of the JVM. I mean, if `java.exe` can do it, why wouldn't my own executable be capable of doing the same? Maybe there's a way of getting a class from a module available to the JVM?

Comment: You do not setup classpath.

Comment: Because you said that I tried setting it to `.`, `./bin` and `.\\bin`, which would be relative paths to both the current directory and to the `bin` directory of the runtime. None of em makes this work. I doubt the error is the classpath but if it is, where should it point to?

Comment: You have to point it to jar with your java classes. Use absolute path to test that it work before switching to relative path.

Comment: Well as I described in the post when using `jlink` I don't get a .jar file. The project in the form of a module is incorporated into the runtime. Exactly where and how I'm not sure, but I know that running the custom made `java.exe` file and listing the available module then my module is in that list.

Comment: I found dupe. It says you have to use "/" instead of "." in class name.

Comment: Yep that seems to have solved the issue! Of course I ran into new issues immediately, right now it's `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`, but at least I got past this problem! Thanks for the help!!